# Outdoor GFCI Plug

Tags: electrical

I have a fountain plugged into this outlet. It quit working. But when both outlets are occupied it works. Not for the strange thing. When you put your hand in the fountain it quits working. Take it out and it starts working again. I have switched out the plug and it still does the same thing. It hasn't always done this. We are in a mobile home and it is 4 years old. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this a drinking-type fountain, or a decorative-type fountain?  Is the GFCI actually tripping, or does the fountain quit working without a corresponding trip?

Comment: Do you have a make and model for the fountain? Any idea how much power it takes?

Comment: It is a decorative fountain. It worked fine when we first purchased it. The GFCI is not tripping the fountain just quits working. Not sure on the model we have had it about 4 months.

Answer (score 1):

Get one of these - not expensive. It will give you a clue as to what's wrong with the wiring.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what that is called?

Comment: @CND Search for "GFCI Tester". You can pay $5-$75 for these but some of the $10 ones work great.